# find element from another jquery element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm not able to find element from my another jquery element.

Could you please suggest, what I'm doing wrong here?

I have following JS code and I want to find that from `total_panels` which div has **wcPanelTabActive** class.

```
var total_panels = $el.find('.wcPanelTab'),
  active_panel = total_panels.find('.wcPanelTabActive');
```

**Chrome console:**

[image]

Comment: Sharing HTML would be better instead of Chrome console

Comment: Problem is that `total_panels.find('.wcPanelTabActive')` will search for any children in `total_panels` that has the class `wcPanelTabActive`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/). As [`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) reduces the set of already matched elements, whereas [`.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) gets descendants of the matched element.

```
active_panel = total_panels.filter('.wcPanelTabActive')
```